# C# random entry from a dictionary on button click

Tags: c#, random, dictionary

I have this working code for my dictionary:

```
dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader("dictionaryfile.csv"))
{
      string line;
      while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          string[] splitword = line.Split(',');  
          dict.Add(splitword[0], splitword[1]);
      }
}
```

I've added a button to my Windows form, and how would I assign a random entry from my dictionary to show in a message box from the button click?

Comment: ...Nothing as I don't know how to do it, that's why i'm asking for help how to do it

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you didn't even google "random c#"?

Comment: Is there any reason not to add entries to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` at the same  time as the dictionary?

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't find anything I understood.

Comment: Then you really need to explain what you don't understand - there are too many options for us to consider. What _exactly_ are you having problems with? Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I don't know how I'd make a random entry from my dictionary show in a message box from my button click.

Comment: Why the downvotes?! because I couldn't understand anything from a google result?

Comment: So is the problem that you don't know how to display a message box or that you don't know how to get a random entry from the dictionary... this is what people don't understand I think.  No one knows where your problem is.  I didn't downvote (yet) but I'm guessing this is why people are voting down.

Comment: I just don't know how to get a random entry from the dictionary. I guess I thought I made that clear enough in the OP but I guess not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class and an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx):

```
var dict = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary(); 
dict.Add("key1", "value1");
dict.Add("key2", "value2");
dict.Add("key3", "value3");
dict.Add("key4", "value4");
// get a random value 
var rnd = new Random();
var randomValue = (String)dict[rnd.Next(0, dict.Count)];
```

**Edit**: Here's an approach using a `Dictionary<String,String>` and the [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) method:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomEntry = dict.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, dict.Count));
String randomKey = randomEntry.Key;
String randomValue = randomEntry.Value;
```

Note that you should not create the random instance in a method, you should either pass it as parameter or use a member variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/284240

Comment: that's sort of what I'm looking for, but I don't understand why you've put the dict.Add code there since i'm not adding anything. I'm just looking to display a random entry on a button click

Comment: Tim's example was a code snippet you can copy and paste into a function to run on its own - for your exact problem you essentially need his last 2 lines of code. If this is for code that is going to be used for more than an assignment/prototype/learning, I strongly recommend you read up on the Random class, as there are a few aspects of random number generations that developers need to know about.

Comment: @user1353517: Edited my answer to provide also a way for a `Dictionary<String,String>`. My code is sample code. Of course you need to reference the "global" dictionary that is populated from form-load(or whencever) in your button's click event handler.

Comment: @L.B Why must I be joking? I'm new to c# and tbh you aren't really helping anything! Thanks Tim, I think I get it now